# jQuery change table cell text color based on text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table which has columns of data that contain status. Two example statuses would be "Rejected" and "Paid"

What I'm wanting to do is changed the text color of the "Rejected" to red and the color of the "Paid" to green.

For the cells that have this status I added a classs to the `td` like:

```
<td class="status">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
</td>
```

So I can easily identify it.

I found I could change the color of all the statuses to Red using:

```
$('.status').css("color", "red");
```

Also I could get the value of the first one by:

```
alert($('.status').html());
```

However I'm unsure how to set a status color based on its text. ie for all "Received" set color to red and for all "Paid" set color to green.

Can somebody enlighten me on how to achieve this?

Am I even following the right approach using jQuery or is there a better css way?

Comment: Unless the value of that column is modified client side. I'd suggest setting the class when the page is drawn in the server side script (PHP,ASP.NET, etc)

Comment: It can change client side via ajax so maybe this won't work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work:

```
$('.status:contains("Paid")').css('color', 'red');
$('.status:contains("Received")').css('color', 'green');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MMEhc/

Answer (score 2):

> Also I could get the value of the first one by...

With that selector you get a collection. And you do `.html()` on the first item in the collection.

You could loop through all `status` cells to check the status and change the color.

```
$('.status').each(function() {
  // check text and do styling
});
```

However this is not preferred (cause it is not needed). And it hurts performance.

You could also use jQuery `.contains()` for this ( http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ ).

Also not really needed. And I think not the best option performance wise.

So the best option (IMHO) is:

Why don't you just add two extra classes to the cells: `status-received` and `status-paid` since you already know the status of the cells while rendering them.

So you just could do:

```
$('.status-received').css("color", "red");
$('.status-paid').css("color", "red");
```

Or drop the jQuery entirely (since we don't need it any more (unless we are going to change the cells dynamically)) and just style the two classes uses CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are printing the table from a database, simply assign a class to the `td` based on the result.

Then assign background color to that class.

```
td.paid {
 display:block;
background-color:red;

}

td.recieved {
 display:block;
background-color:green;
}
```

Why do you need to use javascript for this in the first place?

If I am not mistaken, the above code is jQuery so don't forget to add the Lib if you use that.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do something like this.  I needed to change the background color to red (well, pinkish) when an error occurred and leave it white when everything was good.  Here's my code:

```
warning_color = "#ffffff";

if (error_happened)
    warning_color = "#ffaaaa";

$("#input_box").css('background-color', warning_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td.status').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'Received') {
      $(this).style('color', 'red');
  } // similarly for other statuses
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.status').addClass($(".status").html());
```

Then you could have a `.Paid` class and a `.Received` class and set the css in those classes respectivly. This way if you ever wanted to change the css later it is abstracted away from the javascript. Also you could use these classes in other locations as well if need be.