# Click-event <td> in a table - change colors

Tags: jquery, css, .net, html

I'm doing a table with 6x6 columns () which are now empty with white background.
My assignment is that when clicking on a column, it should change color between green, red and gray (depending on how many times you've clicked the specific column).

Code:

```
    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove; width: 75%; height: 75%;">
        <tr style="border-bottom:medium;">
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:groove; border-left:groove; border-right:groove; border-top:groove;">&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

I have no idea how to proceed, if I should use jQuery functions and such...
Thankful for all answers/tips!

Comment: clicking on column or clicking on a cell ?

Comment: 1st tip : avoid inline styles and use seperate stylesheet.

Comment: you can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986581/jquery-change-table-cell-text-color-based-on-text use external stylesheets

Comment: Do you want to change the colour of one cell or the whole column???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. Hope this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/8gHeD/

HTML

```
<table class="grooveTable">
        <tr >
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

JavaScript

```
colorArray = ['none','red','green','blue'];

$('.grooveTable').on('click','td', function(){
    console.log( $(this).data('color') );
    console.log( colorArray.length );

    color = $(this).data('color') == undefined ? 0 : $(this).data('color')*1;

    if( color == undefined || color == colorArray.length )
    {
        $(this).css('background-color',colorArray[0]);
        $(this).data('color','0');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).css('background-color',colorArray[color+1]);
        $(this).data('color',color+1);
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.grooveTable {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border-bottom:groove;
    border-left:groove; 
    border-right:groove;
    border-top:groove;
}

.grooveTable td {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom:groove; 
    border-left:groove; 
    border-right:groove; 
    border-top:groove;
}
.grooveeTable tr:first {
    border-bottom:medium;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!
Did change the:
if (color == undefined || color == colorArray.length -1)

Answer (score 1):

FOR CHANGING BACKGROUND COLOUR OF THE WHOLE ROW:
You can achieve it like the following: [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cBEph/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('table').on('click','tr',function(){

    switch($(this).attr('class')){
        case 'green':
            $(this).removeClass('green');
            $(this).addClass('red');
            break;
        case 'red':
            $(this).removeClass('red');
            $(this).addClass('gray');
            break;
       case 'gray':
            $(this).removeClass('gray');
           // $(this).addClass('red');
            break;     
       default:
            $(this).addClass('green');                
    }
 });

});
```

FOR CHANGING BACKGROUND COLOUR OF SPECIFIC COLUMN:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('table').on('click','td',function(){

    switch($(this).attr('class')){
        case 'green':
            $(this).removeClass('green');
            $(this).addClass('red');
            break;
        case 'red':
            $(this).removeClass('red');
            $(this).addClass('gray');
            break;
       case 'gray':
            $(this).removeClass('gray');
           // $(this).addClass('red');
            break;     
       default:
            $(this).addClass('green');                
    }
 });

});
```

Comment: he wants column not row

Comment: @sudharsan I thought he meant the whole row. I have asked the user now waiting for the answer. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO  :**  http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/6K6gU/3/

**Our code work on column and not rows . This is what you want**

```
 $('td').click(function(){

          var col=$('tbody td:nth-child('+($(this).parent('tr').index()+1)+')')
          if($(this).hasClass('green')){
               col.removeClass().addClass('red')
          }else if($(this).hasClass('red')){
               col.removeClass().addClass('gray')
          }
            else if($(this).hasClass('gray')){
              col.removeClass().addClass('gray')
          }else {
               col.removeClass().addClass('green')
          }


        })
```

**UPDATE :**

if you want : 
White -> Green-> Red-> Gray --> White

See :
http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/6K6gU/4/

Comment: Not working. If you click one first cell then click on the second cell in the same row. It breaks

Answer (score 0):

Just include a jquery file in your page and use the following script

```
        <script>
            $("table td").on("click", function () {             
                if ($(this).data("isDirty") != undefined) {
                    switch($(this).data("isDirty")) {
                        case '1':                                 
                            $(this).css("background-color", "gray");
                            $(this).data("isDirty", '2');
                            alert($(this).data("isDirty"));
                            break;
                        case '2':                                
                            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
                            $(this).data("isDirty", '3');                                
                            break;
                        default:
                            $(this).css("background-color", "black");
                            $(this).data("isDirty", '4');
                    }                        
                }
                else {
                    $(this).data("isDirty","1");
                    $(this).css("background-color", "green");                        
                }
            });
        </script>
```