# Change color of table text due to search operatives

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have tables which are updating via dynamic ways. I want to change specific texts to colorful ones, during search operation in real time.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7986605/5417479) example, as you can see, it's possible to make them colorful for all document via smart way.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9127872/5417479) second example shows perfectly that how you can create a real time search engine for `table`.

Now, here is the question: Is it possible to make that real time search's results colorfull? Not the whole column or row. I just need to change color `value` of `input` 's matched `value`. Long story short, how can I modify the 2nd example for this?

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/e2106b62/2/

Classic tables I've used in HTML:

```
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table> 

<input id="search">
```

JS I'm trying to use for search (You can find this on 2nd example link):

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

And another JS which I need to implement in search module:

```
$(this).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: So you are wanting color highlighting on search matches?

Comment: Yes. EDIT: But not the whole column or row. Just matched texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off your examples, this does the trick.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrvLbmbb/)

```js
var $cells = $('#table td');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim(input).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;
    
    $cells.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        if(!reg.test(text) || input == ''){
         $(this).css('color','black');
        } else {
            $(this).css('color','green');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {padding: 20px;}
input {margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 2px 3px; width: 209px;}
td {padding: 4px; border: 1px #CCC solid; width: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id="table">
   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. This is what I exactly wanted. Thank you! Also thanks to "dfsq" and "Clive" for perfect examples and "j08691" to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add a different highlight option. This way **it will highlight only the matched text**, case insensitive. You can change the css class to higlight it the way you want, like changing `background-color` too.

<kbd>[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2106b62/42/)</kbd>

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $('table tr').hide().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return ~text.indexOf(val);
    }).show().find("td").each(function(){

        var start = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val);

        if(start !== -1){
            var end = val.length;

            var start_text = start != 0 ? $(this).text().substring(0,start) : "";
            var end_text = $(this).text().substring(start + end);
            var match = $(this).text().substring(start, start + end);

            $(this).html(start_text+'<span class="highlight">'+match+'</span>'+end_text);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This one is working great either. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Nice but how would you make it so it doesn't dissappear the titles of columns (first row)